# OSX cocoa AppSandbox not enabled

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode6.1

I have an .app that uses 2 helper executables.

When I am trying to submit an app to App Store it says :bla bla the following executables must include "com.apple.security.app/contents/MacOS/appName:" bla bla pkgs

When I am adding the enable sandBox and trying to run my app it is crashes on bad access

Can some 1 please provide a simple step by step guide of what to do PLEASE ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Target build settings I had to point  the code signing to the entitlement.plist 
and use code signing (for each target , also had to add the executables in to the bloody project as a targets) . And it solved for me the problem